# Bootstrap confidence interval programming

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, bootstrap

Suppose I have the following data set called form the file `results`. I want to write a bootstrap program using both SAS and R to determine the confidence interval for the mean proportion. If a student get > 50 marks then it is a pass or else it is a fail. The number of replication must be 1000.

exam
23
56
48
87
94
56
98
62
63
45
85
75
49
79
68
58
36
82
81
73
36
69
76
88
96
50
40
49
66
48
70
61
58
63
78
85
78
30

Comment: You can use the R package [boot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf) for this purpose. Consider the commands `boot` and `boot.ci`.

Comment: For SAS, take a look at David Cassell's paper [Don't be Loopy](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf)

Comment: @PeterFlom That is the same advice you gave me. Are you at all familiar with J. D. Opdyke's efficient SAS macros for bootstrapping.  He had a paper on it in a Wiley online journal that I recently refereed.

Comment: I don't know those

Comment: @PeterFlom, MichaelChernick: Peter, The paper to which Michael is referring is now posted under Early Views on the Computational Statistics: WIREs journal webpage at http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/wics.1266/abstract A preprint can be downloaded at http://www.datamineit.com/DMI_publications.htm All feedback is appreciated. Best,
J.D. Opdyke

Answer (score 2):

Here's some `R` code:

```
B = 1000
n = length(data)#data is the name of your vector of data
bootstrap.proportion = rep(NA, n) #vector to store the bootstrap values
for(b in 1:B){
   bootstrap.sample = sample(data, n, replace = TRUE)
   bootstrap.proportion[b] = mean(bootstrap.sample)
}
sort(bootstrap.proportion)
```

The lower limit of the bootstrap confidence interval is the $\alpha / 2$ and the upper limit is the $1-\alpha / 2$ element of this sorted set.

Comment: You are explaining the percentile method bootstrap to the OP.  Maybe we should mention that there are the higher order accurate bootstrap CI such as iterated bootstrap, bootstrap t and BCa.  I imagine the R packages allow the use of these other bootstraps.

Comment: To add to @MichaelChernick 's comment, R has a package called "boot" for bootstrapping.